# SQL database: is it good to just use string?

Tags: sql, database

I am currently working on a school project that has a lot of database columns. I was wondering if it is good practice to just use TEXT/ String as the data type to store data in the database and then just retrieve the data and convert it to int, double or boolean afterwards in the program as needed, or should I already choose the appropriate data type from the start when I build my database? Seems easier to me to just use string as it can easily be edited. Please let me know what you think. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

There are several reasons why you would want to use proper types in your DB

- Memory efficiency: Storing as string when you only want to store eg integers will cost a lot more data. A regular int can store any number from –2147483648 to 2147483647 in 4 bytes, a string takes 1 or 2 bytes per character depending on the encoding, DB, type etc (compare [mysql int](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/integer-types.html) and [mysql char](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/char.html). You should also consider that the size of a SQL column is fixed.
- Cost of conversion: Converting to and from string takes more lines of code and CPU cycles.
- Loss of precision, eg if storing a floating point number as a string
- Order: Ordering on a string number might differ from a numbers natural order, eg the string "10" comes before "2".

I would also imagine that indexing would be more efficient on proper types.

If for any reason you want to store different types in a single column, some might use String in DB for numbers etc. Might still not be as much good practice as it is cannot-think-of-a-better-solution practice.